# bulkTransfer makes the application crash

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I'm developing app for connecting arduino to Android. Everything's working correctly,
 but I've faced a problem:

> When I'm getting data from the arduino it makes the program to crash.

I'm getting data using bulkTransfer and in a Runnable thread every 2milliseconds.

Any help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Log cat would help rather than just stating program is crashing. ....

Comment: how does Logcat works when I'm using the usb to connect two devices?

Comment: What is bulkTransfer?

Comment: Logcat can be used over TCP/IP. See ADB documentation.

Comment: @TurboJ what is the channel in this type of debugging? Wi-Fi or Bluetooth or anything else?

Comment: That will be wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I wanted to access the UI thread inside a runnable thread and it causes the app to crash. Lessening interaction with GUI solved my problem.